# Tem como deixar um commit somente local?

Tags: git, versionamento, commit

A pergunta pode ser meio obvia ou até mesmo confusa. Mas o que eu quero saber é se tem como deixar um commit somente local, por exemplo. Eu estou trabalhando em um funcionalidade e tal, fiz alguns commits importantes, mas de repente vem uma demanda urgente, que preciso concluir e enviar pro servidor. Como faço para enviar apenas o que foi solicitados(Como se eu escolhesse os commits a ser enviados e deixasse os que estava trabalhando antes).

Estou iniciando com git.

Comment: Todo  commit é local até que vc faça o push, seu problema pode ser resolvido com branches, como sugere o Ailton, mas seria interessante vc dar uma estudada no [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O ideal é separar o desenvolvimento de novas funcionalidades por [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ramifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Branching-no-Git-O-que-%C3%A9-um-Branch). Dessa forma, você evita esse tipo de problema.

Uma metodologia para o desenvolvimento através de diferentes branches é o [Git Flow](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/utilizando-o-fluxo-git-flow-e63d5e0d5e04):

Comment: Muito bom. Era isso que eu queria.

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso a seguinte estratégia!
Eu crio uma nova branch baseada na minha branch de desenvolvimento chamada "Partial"
Comito nela tudo que eu não irei adicionar naquele commit.
Faço os comits "Oficiais" na branch de desenvolvimento.

Quando me sentir confortável para voltar naquela linha de pensamento, faço um merge com meu estado atual.

Porem, recomentadia fortemente criar uma branch por funcionalidade, no inicio pode parecer confuso, mas garato que é muito vantajoso.
Para diminuir um pouco a bagunça, pode criar pastas de Branches, exemplo:

> Produtos/compra
>  Produtos/venda
>  Usuarios/testes_unitarios
>   Usuarios/CRUDs
>  Usuarios/Auutenticacao

basta colocar esse "/" entre o nome da pasta e o nome da branch

Comment: Agradeço. Realmente essa organização ajuda bastante. Vou tentar estuda isso ai.